# Why aren't my submodules being removed from '.gitmodules'?

Tags: git

I have removed the existing submodule from my Git repository using commands found in the following answer: [*How do I remove a Git submodule?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/617937)

Although the submodule has been removed (the directory is gone, and the changes have been committed) the submodules still appear in `.gitmodules` just as they were before the removal. The strange thing is, Git doesn't seem to mind that they are listed there, and pretends as if they weren't. `git status` tells me everything is okay, and even running `git submodule init` won't re-add the submodules deleted but still listed there.

Can someone please explain why my deleted submodules still showing up in `.gitmodules`? What is the significance and the role of the `.gitmodules` file in Git’s internal workflow?  And related, is there any harm deleting the `.gitmodules` file now that I am no longer using it?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any harm deleting the `.gitmodules` file now that I am no
>   longer using it?

If you are 100% sure you are not using submodules, then you should be 100% safe removing the `.gitmodules` file.

But I assume the process you went through was something like this. Assuming your submodule is named `spiro_agnew`:

```
git submodule deinit spiro_agnew
```

Then you can just remove the files connected to that submodule like this:

```
git rm -rf spiro_agnew
```

Then just do this to be free of the `.gitmodules` entirely:

```
git rm .gitmodules
```

Comment: Doesn't answer my first question (which you mercilessly edited out ;)

Comment: I want to know the significance and the role of the `.gitmodules` file in Git's internal workflow. Is it used by git to keep track of the submodules (like a config file), or just there to assist the user (like a stage that prevents the user from having to mess with GITs internal config files)? What about if someone else clones my repository; will the existence of the "old" `.gitconfig` file have an effect on them?

Comment: That was a typo, I meant "old .gitcommit". And believe me, I know of the headaches that come with submodules; yet once you learn to use them properly, they become a beautiful asset.